# Is it possible to "script" transactions

Tags: solidity, defi

I would like to write a dapp that allows users to script transactions

i.e.

- swap X for Y every 12 hours
- withdraw 5% from pool every day

I thought about the following steps:

1. The user defines the action to execute and commits it to the platform
2. The platform checks if allowances are needed and if so, it asks them to the user (e.g. in case of swap you'll probably need the permission to transact the user's ERC-20)
3. At the scheduled time the platform triggers the transaction that will cause the withdraw/deposit from the pool or the swap.

I guess that some things could be achieved via double tx (i.e. send token X to platform, platform swaps with token Y, platform sends Y to the user that scheduled the operation), but this has limitations and is more crumblesome than I'd like (and expensive and inefficient).

Is the Ethereum permissions model allowing something like that or I'm hitting a limitation of the design?

Any idea about how I could achieve it?

*NOTE: I don't want to have to ask the user's seed, of course.*

Comment: You could use a smart contract as users wallets then it can be automated without requiring the private key/seed phrase. To schedule a transaction in the future should be possible using an oracle.

Comment: @Ismael you mean that the users would deposit their tokens into the smart contract? I was hoping they could avoid that, otherwise it looks just like another aggregator. The scheduling doesn't worry me, I could even have a off-chain script, it's the former part that I'm interested in.

Comment: I meant each user is the owner of one wallet contract. The contract accepts a signed message and if it matches the owner address it will execute it, the message can do anything, from transferring ethers to invoking any contract. So the user can sign a swap message and schedule it, the system will send the message to the wallet which will validate it and run it.